# Why does my CSS border go to the end of the page?

Tags: html, css, border, center

I have been learning HTML/CSS with codecademy, and I have this problem with my CSS border. I need my h1 to be centered with a border, but I don't want that border to go to the ends of the page. Here is my code

```
<h1 style="color:#0034ff; padding:20px; border-style:ridge; border-width:5px; text-align:center;">HTML Testing Page</h1>
```

I plan on making a seperate style sheet soon, I just put the CSS in the HTML document to test it. This border goes to the ends of the page, and if I put display:inline or display:inline-block my text is no longer centered. How could I make the border just go next to the text without sacrificing centered text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the `h1` is a [block element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes), but I think you are looking for this:

```
h1 {
    color:#0034ff;
    padding:20px;
    border-style:ridge;
    border-width:5px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* <--- */
    display: table; /* <--- */ 
}​
```

This will center the heading without it taking the entire width of the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/rm3Fk/11/

Answer (score 6):

Add `display:inline-block`

h1 tag is block element so it is occupying entire space .

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/rm3Fk/

If you want the h1 tag to center align to the page then you can use `display:table; margin:0 auto`

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/rm3Fk/17/

Comment: The heading is not centered for me (Chromium 18.0.1025.168 Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: ya in that case table is fine as you answered. I answered to get rid of the full width border

Comment: I didn't copy and need not to copy simple things, If i had did that I wouldn't have appreciate your answer. And I respect you for your age

Answer (score 1):

Hi now used to  `display:inline-block;` in your **h1 tag**

```
<h1 style="color:#0034ff; padding:20px; border-style:ridge; border-width:5px;display:inline-block; text-align:center;">HTML Testing Page</h1>
```

All Heading Element is **block** Element

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/r5C5mDtx)***